# How do I set the coordinates of a new point using Openlayers?

Tags: javascript, mapping, coordinates, gis, openlayers

I have a map which I created using Openlayers. The map takes points from a database and plots them on the map upon pressing a button on the page. These work as expected. What I would like to do is add a new point when the user doubleclicks somewhere on the map. I'm not worried about saving it to the database yet and this is purely just to add a new point to the existing layer with the database-loaded points on.

My code looks like this currently:

```
map.on('dblclick', function (evt) {
console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
addMarker(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
```

and

```
function addMarker(evt) {



var array = evt.toString().split(",").map(Number);
var long = array[0];
var lat = array[1];
toastr.info(long);
toastr.info(lat);
var marker = new ol.Feature(
    new ol.geom.Point([long, lat])
);



var zIndex = 1;
marker.setStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [0.5, 36], 
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "pixels",
        opacity: 1,
        src: "images/pinother.png", 
        zIndex: zIndex
    })),
    zIndex: zIndex
})];

vectorSource.addFeature(marker);}
```

This does create a point on the map with the correct look, but it's always at the origin point; 0,0 latitude/longitude!

Using toastr (a styled alerts function) in my addMarker function I can see that variables "lat" and "long" are being populated correctly, so it must be part of the

```
var marker = new ol.Feature(
new ol.geom.Point([long, lat])
```

point creation that I am not doing correctly. The coordinates being passed have large values e.g "62.915233039476135", is there a limit on how long this should be or am I missing something else that is preventing my new point taking any coordinates?

Comment: Features should be in map coordinates, so no need to transform, just use `addMarker(evt.coordinate)`

Comment: Thanks Mike, as you said I had the coordinates being transformed to a different projection (ESPG:4326 vs ESPG:3857) which the code didn't like

Answer (score 0):

As [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike) indicated in the comments, just pass the coordinates from the event to the `addMarker` function.

FYI - you also have issues with the marker styling.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_addMarkerOnDblClick.html)

relevant code:

```
  map.on('dblclick', function (evt) {
    console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
    addMarker(evt.coordinate);
  });

  function addMarker(coordinates) {
    console.log(coordinates);
    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
    var zIndex = 1;
    marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [0.5, 36], 
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "pixels",
        opacity: 1,
        src: "mapIcons/pinother.png", 
        zIndex: zIndex
      })),
      zIndex: zIndex
    }));
    vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
  }
```

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayer,
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
  console.log(map.getInteractions());
  var dblClickInteraction;
  // find DoubleClickZoom interaction
  map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
      dblClickInteraction = interaction;
    }
  });
  // remove from map
  map.removeInteraction(dblClickInteraction)
  var vectorSource = vectorLayer.getSource();

  function addMarker(coordinates) {
    console.log(coordinates);
    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
    var zIndex = 1;
    marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [0.5, 36],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "pixels",
        opacity: 1,
        src: "https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png",
        zIndex: zIndex
      })),
      zIndex: zIndex
    }));
    vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
  }
  map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
    addMarker(evt.coordinate);
  });
  var south = 24.0;
  var west = -125.8;
  var north = 49.6;
  var east = -66.4;
  // [maxx, maxy, minx, miny]
  var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent([east, north, west, south], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  map.getView().fit(extent, {
    size: map.getSize(),
    padding: [5, 5, 5, 5]
  });
</script>
```